# How to set face to different property by detecting the background-mode

Tags: faces

```lisp
(set-face-attribute 'hl-line nil
                      (cl-case (alist-get 'background-mode (frame-parameters))
                        ('light ; darker percent 5%
                         :background (color-darken-name (face-background 'highlight) 5)
                         )
                        ('dark
                         :background (color-lighten-name (face-background 'default) 3)
                         ))
                      )
```

The upper code does not work. I hope some one can correct this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The arguments to `set-face-attribute` after the `FRAME` arg need to come in pairs.

But you are passing only the new color value, not the pair `:background` followed by that new color value.

```el
(set-face-attribute 
 'hl-line 
 nil 
 :background    ; <===== THIS WAS MISSING
 (cl-case (alist-get 'background-mode (frame-parameters))
   ('light :background (color-darken-name (face-background 'highlight) 5))
   ('dark :background (color-lighten-name (face-background 'default) 3))))
```

Comment: Even you said so, but I still don't know how to write this. Can you show me a code?

Comment: Sorry, because the network delay, your initial answer is not included the code.